# Mysql - Find field value that equals $variable echo another fields value for that row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated. Hope this makes sense.

I am trying to echo back from db a list of the users friends.
The current user comes form $userid.

DB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wallfriends` (
  `mem_id_from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mem_id_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `confirm` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `sender` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The bit I am struggling with is to get the friends id from the db that is not the current $userid (Find field value that equals $userid echo another fields value for that row: so it could be mem_id_from OR mem_id_to).

Below is my script, but i just cant get my head around the structure of what i need to code.

**(modified from josnidhin's answer)**

```
    <?php
$my_friends = mysql_query('SELECT * from wallfriends WHERE (mem_id_from = '.$userid.') OR (mem_id_to = '.$userid.') AND confirm = 1');

$available_friends = mysql_fetch_array($my_friends);
foreach($available_friends as $friend)
{
  if($friend['mem_id_from']=== $userid && $friend['mem_id_to']!== $userid)
  {
    echo '<a href="'.$path.'profile.php?userid='.$friend['mem_id_to'].'">'
    echo '<img src="'.$post_avatar.'" width="70px" height="70px" border="0" alt="" />'
    echo '</a>';
  } 
  else if($friend['mem_id_from']!== $userid && $friend['mem_id_to']=== $userid)
  {
    echo '<a href="'.$path.'profile.php?userid='.$friend['mem_id_from'].'">'
    echo '<img src="'.$post_avatar.'" width="70px" height="70px" border="0" alt="" />'
    echo '</a>';
  }
}


        ?>
```

After josnidhin's answer, I tried:

```
$userid = '4276';

print_r($available_friends);

Array ( [0] => 3441 [mem_id_from] => 3441 [1] => 4276 [mem_id_to] => 4276 [2] => 1 [confirm] => 1 [3] => 3441 [sender] => 3441 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt really understand what you are asking but I think this what you are looking for

```
<?php
    $my_friends = mysql_query('SELECT * from wallfriends WHERE (mem_id_from = '.$userid.') OR (mem_id_to = '.$userid.') AND confirm = 1');

    while ($friend = mysql_fetch_array($my_friends, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      if($friend['mem_id_from']=== $userid && $friend['mem_id_to']!== $userid)
      {
        echo '<a href="'.$path.'profile.php?userid='.$friend['mem_id_to'].'">'
        echo '<img src="'.$post_avatar.'" width="70px" height="70px" border="0" alt="" />'
        echo '</a>';
      } 
      else if($friend['mem_id_from']!== $userid && $friend['mem_id_to']=== $userid)
      {
        echo '<a href="'.$path.'profile.php?userid='.$friend['mem_id_from'].'">'
        echo '<img src="'.$post_avatar.'" width="70px" height="70px" border="0" alt="" />'
        echo '</a>';
      }
    }

    ?>
```

Checkout the docs at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: thanks for the response: this seems to be what i am after. although it is not echoing anything back. I have added else {echo'not worked';} after the else if and it echos that back. So the if statements are not being triggered. Any ideas?

Comment: probably the comparision try changing '===' to '==' and '!==' to '!='. If it works then later fix the datatype of variables

Comment: yes already tried that and it did the same. I have updated my question from your answer. I have printed the array. The array seems wierd though as it only displays 1 row. If i run in SQL i get 4 rows.

Comment: Still only one row in array. Array ( [mem_id_from] => 3441 [mem_id_to] => 4276 [confirm] => 1 [sender] => 3441 )                  But it should still at lease echo that!

Comment: Yes mysql_fetch_array fetched one row from the result and moves the internal pointer ahead. That why I added it into the while loop so it will get all the result rows from your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$my_friends = mysql_query('SELECT * from wallfriends WHERE (mem_id_from = '.$userid.') OR (mem_id_to = '.$userid.') AND confirm = 1');

$available_friends = mysql_fetch_array($my_friends);
foreach($available_friends as $friend)
{
if($friend['mem_id_from']=== $userid && $friend['mem_id_to']!== $userid){
echo'<a href="'.$path.'profile.php?userid='.$friend['mem_id_to'].'">
    <img src="'.$post_avatar.'" width="70px" height="70px" border="0" alt="" />
</a>';
} else if($friend['mem_id_from']!== $userid && $friend['mem_id_to']=== $userid){
echo'<a href="'.$path.'profile.php?userid='.$friend['mem_id_from'].'">
    <img src="'.$post_avatar.'" width="70px" height="70px" border="0" alt="" />
</a>';
}
}

?>
```

Comment: I realize this is very old, but some explanation alongside your code would be helpful